Can a 32-bit Windows XP guest see a NTFS HDD with one 8TB GPT partition as a VirtualBox shared folder and read/write files on/to it?
Can a 32-bit Windows XP guest see a NTFS HDD with one 8TB GPT partition as a VirtualBox shared folder and read/write files on/to it?
Background
A 32-bit Windows XP physical machine cannot access more than 2TB of total partitioned space on an internal hard disk.

[Ques.] How big can a GPT disk be
[Ans] ... Windows XP and the original release of Windows Server 2003 have a limit of 2TB per physical disk, including all partitions.... — Windows and GPT FAQ | Microsoft Learn

Furthermore, it cannot access a GPT partitoned disk of any size.

[Ques.] Whether the 32-bit version of Windows XP read, write, and boot from GPT disks
[Ans.] No. The 32-bit version will see only the Protective MBR. The EE partition will not be mounted or otherwise exposed to application software. — Windows and GPT FAQ | Microsoft Learn

Assume:

The host machine is running a flavor of Debian 12 (bookworm) for 64-bit PC (amd64).
No changes have been made to Windows XP itself, such as replacing its system files (Read GPT hard disk on Windows XP - Windows XP - MSFN); and no software has been installed in Windows XP to make it GPT capable, such as Paragon GPT loader.
Switching to a 64-bit Windows XP virtual machine is not allowed. (Although, Windows XP x64 Edition can use GPT disks for data only.)
The host has mounted the 8GB GPT mono-partitioned internal NTFS hard drive as /media/win_f.
If the Windows XP guest can see the drive, it sees it as (VirtualBox shared folder) drive F: and uses it only for data files (not system or configuration files).

If the answer is "yes" please explain how this is possible.

Are we being given an exam question here?

No, I'm just trying to find out if this might work before I succumb to temptation and buy an 8TB HDD for storage.

Windows XP doesn’t support GPT. This definitely is an example question

@Ramhound: It does, in the x64 and IA64 versions. That doesn't seem to be the question being asked either way; it's already included as part of the background of the question, if you'd read far enough.

@grawity_u1686—Windows XP 64-bit and Windows XP IA64 were individual licensed versions. There is less than a 0% chance the author is using either of those products, considering IA64 was abandoned more than a decade ago and VirtualBOx is incapable of supporting it.

Disk-related limits do not apply because the Windows XP system is not actually accessing a disk as far as it is aware.
The drive letter within the guest is mapped to an UNC path corresponding to what the guest thinks is a network share on the \\vboxsvr host, and (as the name "VirtualBox shared folders" implies) it is being accessed using a file-oriented protocol (much like SMB or 9p, but custom to VirtualBox and transported over its proprietary PCI channel).
Therefore, similar to having Windows access an SMB share, the VM is not involved in parsing the actual partition table nor the actual filesystem that's being shared – and is not even aware of the partition table type being used (if any) nor of the filesystem type being used – so any limits the guest OS might have in that regard are irrelevant.
The only actual filesystem access is done by the VirtualBox process on the host, again using file-level operations through the mount-point being shared.

I thought it might be a "yes" as affirmed by grawity_u1686 who writes that "disk-related limits do not apply." Although, I certainly could not explain the technical details. Thank you.
